# Unable to retrive marathi font text from database in proper way in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on web application in asp.net in that I want to take user name in marathi language,when i store marathi text in database it store in unknown format so I am not able retrieve it properly? please help me

I am try this query

```
INSERT INTO DemoMarathi(English, Marathi)
VALUES     ('translate', N'भाषांतर ')
```

It insert and retrieve proper word but how it use in application

Comment: You have to define your database fields to support unicode values (for example, in SQL Server, nvarchar instead of varchar).

Comment: I am take for it nvarchar in sql but the problem is that I am not save marathi text in database it shows like ????? this

Comment: It might just be your database browser that cannot display unicode? What are you using?

Comment: where you want to retrive text? `Sql Management studio` or `Asp.net web page`.Please specify

Comment: I want to retrieve text on asp.net web page,but it retrive in "?????" this format

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose an appropriate collation that can handle Marathi text properly. Then you should choose NVarChar or NText data types, and after configuring these two, you are able to store/retrieve them in a correct manner.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please refer this one.

```
Create table Test_Nchar (strText nvarchar(max))

insert into Test_Nchar values ( N'भाषांतर ')
insert into Test_Nchar values ( N'Neeraj')

SELECT * FROM Test_Nchar WHERE strText LIKE N'भा%'
```

[image: This one work for me in Sql Management Studio]